# MKPinAnnotationView unable to set custom image

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, mkpinannotationview, mapkit

I have a MKPinAnnotationView and in my viewForAnnotation method, I do the following:

```
customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"];
```

I have added blah.png to my resources (by dragging the file in)

But I still see the stock pin and not my image.  Am I doing something wrong?  Here is the complete code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: In the question you say you have a "MKPinAnnotationView" but in the code you are (correctly) creating a "MKAnnotationView" so which is it?  Is the viewForAnnotation method getting called?  Maybe the map view's delegate is not set.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks.  BTW: can I get a callout with a custom image?

Comment: Your question and code snippet do not match up.

Answer (score 1):

To get a callout with a custom image, in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, you can set either the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` or `rightCalloutAccessoryView` to your image (although the one on the right is usually used for a disclosure button):

```
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = 
    [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];
```